# Python element wise operations in parallel

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a simple way to do element wise numpy array operations of python in parallel.

I am trying to do `a = b * c + d` (all 3d arrays, `[9, 200, 200]` ). I can't get this to run in parallel because `htop` (on Linux) shows me only one thread being used when I run the above step for thousands of iterations. I ran it on a cluster too with multiple nodes, but same results.

Tried both Python 2 and 3.

No independent `for`-loops, so cython won't help much?

All I need is just simple addition/multiplication of numpy arrays in parallel.

Thanks

Comment: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html

Comment: The linked duplicate is several years old.  There may be some newer discussions that are just as good.